# Enzyme fails to recognize date

Tags: javascript, typescript, enzyme

I've got a table, that get's rendered right after the data fetching from API. One of the properties is a ISO date String, which I parse to `.localeDateString()`.

I assert in tests that my component been given appropriate date String like:

```
...
await waitFor(() => {
    dashboard.update()
    expect(dashboard.containsMatchingElement(
                <Table merchants={[
                    {
                        "userId": "userId",
                        "createdAt": "9.03.2021, 13:58:30"
                    }
                ]}/>
```

and it returns false. If I don't map the date to LocaleString it works just fine.

My mapping function looks like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        getMerchants()
            .then(response => {
                setMerchants(mapToMerchants(response))

...

const mapToMerchants = (response: any) => {
        return response.merchants.map((merchant: Merchant) =>
            (new Merchant(merchant.userId, formatDate(merchant.createdAt)))
        );
    }

...

export const formatDate = (date: string | undefined): string => {
    if (isInvalidDate(date)) return new Date(0).toLocaleString('pl-PL')
    return new Date(date!!).toLocaleString('pl-PL')
}

...

let [merchants, setMerchants] = useState<Merchant[]>([])
```

I've tried to put dashboard.debug() to see the real value of the `createdAt` and it is the same as in the tests. Do you have any ideas what can go wrong?